P values not matching data in mixed effects analysis
I have a dataset that consists of the oxygen consumption (MO2) values for 3 different species of fish. My experiment was a repeated measures design where I measured MO2 of the same 14 fish per species at 4 different temperature points (15C, 20C, 25C and 30C). I also recorded the weight of all fish used in the study. I am trying to run a mixed effects model in R (with a repeated measures design) with weight included as a covariate  as weight is known to impact oxygen consumption (MO2).
I have a repeated measures mixed effects model I am running in R with weight as a covariate. I used the following code to run the model:
model_interaction <- lmer(MO2 ~ Temperature * Species + Weight + (1|Subject_ID), data = MO2mixed)

I then ran a post hoc test because I wanted to know if there were differences in the MO2 values between each of the species at each of the given temperatures. I used this code:
emm_interaction <- emmeans(model_interaction, pairwise ~ Species | Temperature)
pairwise_interaction <- pairs(emm_interaction)
print(pairwise_interaction)

However, when I get the results of the post hoc test, the p values and significance dont line up at all with how the graph of my data looks. For example, the emmeans function gives me the following stats:
Temperature = 30:
 contrast  estimate    SE    df t.ratio p.value
 FTD - JD   0.16016 0.109 123.5   1.465  0.3115
 FTD - RBD  0.47990 0.109 129.1   4.413  0.0001
 JD - RBD   0.31974 0.123 101.3   2.600  0.0286

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 

However, it doesn't make any sense with my graph (see attached) where at 30 degrees it looks the largest difference is between FTD and JD, but in the stats the p value says it isnt significant in the least.
Any ideas on why this may be happening?
For some of my data there was missing points for individuals at higher temperatures, as the fish became unable to handle these temperatures. As a result for some individuals there are data points for earlier temperatures but NAs for higher temperatures. Could this be a problem? I thought mixed effects models were capable of handling blank values though?
Any advice why my p values arent matching the relationships given in the graph of my dataset at all?

Data Below:
structure(list(Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("FTD", "JD", "RBD"), class = "factor"), 
   Weight = c(3.24, 1.54, 2.13, 1.35, 3.1, 2.02, 2.48, 1.82, 
   1.99, 1.9, 1.09, 2.22, 1.03, 2.17, 3.24, 1.54, 2.13, 1.35, 
   3.1, 2.02, 2.48, 1.82, 1.99, 1.9, 1.09, 2.22, 1.03, 2.17, 
   3.24, 1.54, 2.13, 1.35, 3.1, 2.02, 2.48, 1.82, 1.99, 1.9, 
   1.09, 2.22, 1.03, 2.17, 3.24, 1.54, 2.13, 2.02, 2.48, 1.82, 
   1.99, 1.9, 1.09, 2.22, 1.03, 2.17, 2.76, 3.2, 2.3, 3.76, 
   2.74, 3.65, 3.13, 2.97, 2.55, 1.87, 1.61, 3.03, 2.76, 3.63, 
   3.2, 2.3, 1.37, 3.76, 2.74, 3.13, 2.55, 1.87, 1.61, 3.03, 
   2.76, 3.63, 3.2, 2.3, 1.37, 3.76, 2.74, 3.13, 2.55, 1.87, 
   1.61, 3.03, 2.76, 3.63, 2.3, 1.37, 3.76, 2.74, 3.13, 2.55, 
   1.87, 1.61, 3.03, 1.33, 1.48, 1.68, 1.54, 1.39, 1.58, 1.44, 
   1, 0.86, 0.69, 0.49, 0.43, 0.69, 0.48, 1.33, 1.48, 1.68, 
   1.54, 1.39, 1.58, 1.44, 1, 0.86, 0.69, 0.49, 0.43, 0.69, 
   0.48, 1.33, 1.48, 1.68, 1.54, 1.39, 1.58, 1.44, 1, 0.86, 
   0.69, 0.49, 0.43, 0.48, 1.33, 1.48, 1.68, 1.54, 1.58, 1.44, 
   1, 0.86, 0.69, 0.49, 0.43, 0.48), MO2 = c(0.939755565, 0.543795691, 
   0.539350779, 0.268165909, 0.856442856, 0.343980219, 0.454790133, 
   0.576237414, 0.538000297, 0.459098499, 0.405003218, 0.992123237, 
   0.181399928, 0.631885581, 1.224804904, 0.552493777, 0.654319128, 
   0.286527771, 1.406616438, 0.619243441, 0.993801804, 0.751413064, 
   0.799830254, 0.777114788, 0.555263781, 0.851031839, 0.579932461, 
   0.877156968, 1.097122281, 0.67673199, 0.612703501, 0.340423289, 
   1.485339134, 0.634680178, 1.229212392, 0.83482771, 1.017664498, 
   1.082292489, 0.386094625, 1.032827354, 0.476059993, 0.879539839, 
   0.569426449, 0.640213759, 0.327494814, 0.313225741, 0.469474034, 
   0.114115689, 0.853071598, 0.708031422, 0.17521215, 0.730065719, 
   0.353580062, 0.787947081, 1.196828098, 1.231840134, 0.409671984, 
   1.390778763, 0.57389837, 1.234291669, 0.200660785, 0.698507062, 
   0.755517754, 0.580350268, 0.168902497, 0.650146333, 0.769421211, 
   1.895859328, 1.504624666, 0.870422893, 0.799780534, 1.621527816, 
   0.33646381, 0.341667673, 0.451040835, 0.344520353, 0.347955902, 
   1.146230547, 0.50649262, 1.294985069, 0, 0.749876882, 0.155121379, 
   0.886443233, 0.732656269, 0.105450622, 0.336730162, 0.523647227, 
   0.423533713, 1.197225035, 0, 0.173872158, -0.053493458, 0.367918869, 
   0, 0.43009874, 0, 0, 0.510262517, 0.262666878, 0.541747871, 
   0.224252607, 0.36422344, 0.460574465, 0.48148195, 0.397705108, 
   0.675139734, 0.41667177, 0.337382582, 0.442365737, 0.216105681, 
   0.143674104, 0.066925632, 0.084608847, 0.18056507, 0.419911695, 
   0.675106362, 0.760343919, 0.517202155, 0.311614245, 0.69578795, 
   0.537929834, 0.328894409, 0.463124021, 0.048725777, 0.157052443, 
   0.148971995, 0.38352815, 0.236236667, 0.34179618, 0.60676533, 
   -0.00899474, 0.200059872, 0.137292387, 0.433533566, 0.49560458, 
   0.37128264, 0.238961912, -0.013610767, 0.122948052, 0.03960723, 
   0.135467019, 0.121555008, 0.322338175, 0, 0.113439316, 0.100552448, 
   0.072530626, 0.239477483, 0, 0.140301381, 0, 0.038999365, 
   0), Temperature = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
   4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
   4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
   1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
   2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
   4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("15", 
   "20", "25", "30"), class = "factor"), Subject_ID = structure(c(1L, 
   2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
   1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
   1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
   1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
   17L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 15L, 
   16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 15L, 
   16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 15L, 
   16L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
   31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
   29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
   41L, 42L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
   39L, 40L, 42L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
   39L, 40L, 42L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
   "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
   "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
   "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", 
   "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-154L), class = "data.frame")```


The plot shows the observed mean/std err. MO2 for each (species, temperature) combination? And do you treat temperature as a continuous predictor (thus also assuming that the association between temperature and MO2 is linear though the line is allowed to vary by species)?

I am treating temperature as a continuous predictor, assuming linear association between temperature and MO2. And yes the plot shows mean and SE MO2 for each species temperature combination.

Then I think this explains the p-value results. To see this, you could try adding the predictions E(MO2 | temperature & species) to the plot. Your plot suggests strongly that the linearity assumption is a poor choice.

PS: I've edited the formatting of the outputs by enclosing them in three backticks: ```. And I removed the image of the table as it's redundant. It's best to aovide adding code, data, errors, etc as images for these reasons.

So is there a way I could do a repeated measures mixed effects analysis with weight as a covariate that would tell me significant differences between species at each temperature point that doesnt necessarily assume linearity?

Yes, there are many threads on CV on this topic. One option is to declare temperature a categorical variable, with factor(temperature). This will allow you to test "if there were differences in the MO2 values between each of the species at each of the given temperatures" without making assumptions about the function form of the association.

So I tried this, converted temperature to a factor, and I still ended up with the same P value results.

Is it possible to share the data?  There are several ways to add data to a question, probably the easiest method is to copy/paste the output of dput(<yourData>).

Yep! Does that work for you?

Thanks, the data helps. You've been treating temperature as a categorical var (not a continuous var) from the start. That's why the p-values didn't change: factor(Temp) is the same as Temp in this case. This also means that my previous comments are mostly irrelevant. Now I'm thinking it's important that the species are quite different in weight, and that weight is a good predictor of MO2 at low temperatures. Your data is interesting; I'll take a deeper look to write an answer.

A handful of MO2 values are negative / exactly 0. On the surface this doesn't make sense for a measure of oxygen consumption. Could this be measurement error?

I don't see any control data for fish-free oxygen concentrations versus temperature. Given that you have data points that suggest that fish are making oxygen, I suspect that the calibration of your oxygen analysis might be temperature-dependent.

Why do you want all of those p-values? Surely a null hypothesis that all fish have the same oxygen consumption rate and that they have the same responses to temperature is biologically untenable. Maybe you are interested in the changes in oxygen consumption with temperature rather than the actual levels of consumption.

the 0's are intentional and the negative values are also part of the analysis. the MO2 values are calculated from a difference between maximum MO2 and baseline MO2. I want p values because I want to know which of the three species has the highest MO2 difference for each given temperature. That is essentially all i am trying to do. The test i ran seemed to be working and had a proper set up until the p values gave completely wonky results and I cannot figure out why.

What do you mean by the test seemed to be working? Even though it's good that your suspicions were raised by the p-values, the bigger issue is that you skipped the phase of checking that the model actually fits the data. You can't make valid inferences otherwise.

The model is mis-specified (it doesn't explain the data), so the p-values are not meaningful. The lesson is to check the model before making inferences from it.
A great way to get more insight into the data before proposing models is to visualize it. This is the graph I came up with:


There is one panel for each temperature setting: 15, 20, 25, 30 (degrees), with weight on the x-axis and MO2 on the y-axis.
Each dot is a fish; the species is indicated by the shape and color.
Subject IDs are not shown explicitly but, as weight is measured once, fish are plotted at the same x coordinate in each panel. So a fish is more or less identified by its horizontal position and shape/color.
Grey dots indicate missing MO2 measurements.
The vertical gray segments in the second to fourth panel indicate change in oxygen consumption from the previous temperature setting: solid line for increase in MO2 and dashed line for a decrease in MO2.

Some observations:

The relationship between weight and MO2 is reasonably linear but the strength of the association changes as the temperature increases.
The variance in MO2 also increases with weight.
The species are different in weight. (So the differences between species are in part confounded with the effect of weight.)
Some oxygen consumption values are exactly equal to 0 or even negative, esp. at 30 degrees. The heaviest RBD fish are affected by this issue the most. It may be a data issue but I suspect they didn't survive at that temperature.

Based on these observations, it's necessary to (at least) add a temperature—weight interaction. I also let the residual std. error σ depend on the weight to deal with the pattern of non-constant variance. I know how to fit this model with {brms}.
model <- bf(
  MO2 ~ Temperature * Species + Temperature * Weight + (1 | Subject_ID),
  sigma ~ Weight,
  family = gaussian()
)
fit <- brm(model, data = MO2mixed)

Fortunately, {emmeans} supports brms models, so exactly the same snippet of code still works to estimate pairwise differences. Since this a Bayesian model, emmeans doesn't report a p-value but the highest posterior density (HPD) interval. (See What is a Highest Density Region (HDR)?.)
#> Temperature = 30:
#>  contrast  estimate lower.HPD upper.HPD
#>  FTD - JD    0.3063    0.1431     0.462
#>  FTD - RBD   0.2210    0.0314     0.419
#>  JD - RBD   -0.0876   -0.3134     0.120
#> 
#> Point estimate displayed: median 
#> HPD interval probability: 0.95

Okay, so no p-values but the contrasts (the pairwise differences) agree with the sample differences between the species at temperature = 30. Also, the credible intervals for FTD - JD and FTD - RBD exclude 0, which agrees with the OP's expectation.
However, I still argue that an inference such as "the data is consistent with no difference between JD and RBD at temperature = 30" is incorrect: there might be no statistical difference but there is quite a bit of a practical difference if most RBD fish died (as large fish seem to be more affected by high temperature) and most JD survived (being small fish, with low oxygen consumption at both low and high temperature).

+1 A very nice re-analysis and explanation.

this is awesome - thanks
